# WP Bootstrap menu dropdown menu on hover

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav

My Wordpress (bootstrap) nav menu is added as follows:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mx-auto',
                    'fallback_cb'     => '',
                    'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
                    'depth'           => 3,
                    'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                )
            ); ?>
```

How do I make it unfold the drop down menu on hover as opposed to click?

Thank you

EDIT: added the generated html

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
            <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav mx-auto"><li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item menu-item-7"><a title="Home" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-34"><a title="About us" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/about-us/" class="nav-link">About us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-126"><a title="What&#039;s on" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/events/" class="nav-link">What&#8217;s on</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-284"><a title="Rider" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/ridehq/" class="nav-link">Rider</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-33"><a title="Join the club" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/join-the-club/" class="nav-link">Join the club</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-35"><a title="Youth" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/youth/" class="nav-link">Youth</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item menu-item-36 dropdown"><a title="Adults" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Adults <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class=" dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-87"><a title="Sunday Morning Rides" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/sunday-morning-rides/" class="nav-link">Sunday Morning Rides</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-242"><a title="Competitive" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/competitive/" class="nav-link">Competitive</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>                     </div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: you will need javascript / jquery / css for it. do not change the php. try this: https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/frDqh

Comment: Thank you. Will try it.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to add some css classes to the above php code for the jquery to work?

Comment: post the html code the php code generates and i can help

Comment: updated above. Thank you